# lvalue to rvalue conversion for unordered map

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

Received the parameters from an external library :

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::unordered_map<string, string>' to 'std::unordered_map<string, string> &&' (aka 'unordered_map<basic_string<char>, basic_string<char> > &&') for 1st argument

void someMethod(shared_ptr<Context> ctx, std::unordered_map<string, string>&& config) {
    ctx->setConfigOverrides(config);
}

// From Context :
// I can't change following method :
void setConfigOverrides(
    std::unordered_map<string, string>&& configOverrides) {
    setConfigOverrides(make_shared<const MemConfig>(move(configOverrides)));
}
```

Comment: Did you perchance `ctx->setConfigOverrides(std::move(config));`

Comment: What do you mean by the comment ? I have removed some complexity from the code.

Comment: It means, the line line that reads `ctx->setConfigOverrides(config);` should be `ctx->setConfigOverrides(std::move(config));` And whether you realize it or not, you answered by question.

Comment: It worked. Only if I knew more of C++. Do you want to post it as answer ? It would be easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing moving your input argument on to the next receiver of said-same. This:

```
ctx->setConfigOverrides(config);
```

should be this:

```
ctx->setConfigOverrides(std:move(config));
```

Proper forwarding requires it. Just because `config` was passed in as an rval-reference doesn't mean it isn't concrete under the hood. An excellent article on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) explains the concept well (not surprising; that site is really amazing, and should be bookmarked if you haven't already). And if you think the syntax is complicated, it gets worse with perfect-forwarding through template deduction. Thankfull, `std::forward<>` does all the heavy lifting there.

Anyway, that was what was missing. Hope it helps.